# TypeError : pack() got multiple values for argument 'name'

Tags: tensorflow

I implemented a ConvNet in Tensorflow: with 3 Conv-Relu-Pool layers, one FC layer and 5 softmax classifiers.
In the graph (at training), I concat all the 5 softmax into a single tensor:

```
train_prediction = tf.pack([tf.nn.softmax(logit_d1),\
                   tf.nn.softmax(logit_d2), tf.nn.softmax(logit_d3),\
                   tf.nn.softmax(logit_d4),tf.nn.softmax(logit_d5)],\ 
                   0, name="tf_train_prediction")
```

When I run the code, I get the error shown in the title.

In the graph, I have 2 more `tf.pack()` operation: one named "`validation_prediction`", and one without name. Also, in the code, I do not have duplicated name for  `tf_train_prediction`.
I don't understand why I get that Err message. Let me know if you have suggestions. FYI, I am running Tensorflow version 0.11

For completeness, below are the 2 other tf.pack() ops:

```
valid_prediction = tf.pack(\
           [tf.nn.softmax(val_logit_d1),tf.nn.softmax(val_logit_d2),\    
            tf.nn.softmax(val_logit_d3),tf.nn.softmax(val_logit_d4),\
            tf.nn.softmax(val_logit_d5)], 0, name="valid_prediction")

predicted_digits = tf.transpose( tf.pack(\
        [tf.argmax(softmax_d1[:,:], 1),tf.argmax(softmax_d2[:,:],1),\
         tf.argmax(softmax_d3[:,:], 1),tf.argmax(softmax_d4[:,:],1),\
         tf.argmax(softmax_d5[:,:], 1)]) )
```

Comment: This looks like you have a function call like: tf.pack(..., name="something", name="something else").

Comment: Are you sure the error is about this `tf.pack` and not the others? Could you post the others?

Comment: If I take out the axis value (`0`) in the `tf.pack(...)`, then I don't get the error. Looks like the `0` is interpreted as a value of the argument `name`. I also tried to include `axis=`, i.e `tf.pack([.....], axis=0, name=....)`, but then I get an error (argument `axis` is not recognized.). According to the tensorflow webpage, this is how `tf.pack()` should be used though: `tf.pack(values, axis=0, name='pack')`.

Comment: Strange :P Are you sure you're using r0.11? It behaves like [r0.9 API](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/array_ops.html#pack). Check by printing `tf.__version__` in your code.

Comment: good catch @sygi. I did not update TF in the right environment. Now, it's done, and code works! I checked `tf.pack()`, with/without `axis=0` and I don't get the error anymore